# datatable button export not showing in adminLTE/Bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

Hi there I'm using Datatables in AdminLte, and I'm Trying to include the export button for Datatables, when using normal  html without any admin lte its work normal 
[image]
but when i'm trying to integrate it with ADMINLTE the export button is missing like this
[image]
my code is like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script>    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [

            {extend:'excel',action:newExportAction}
        ],
           "processing": true,
         "serverSide": true,
         "ajax": "http://localhost/data/verify/getDataEmployeeFromMantra"

    } );</script>
  <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                      <thead>
                          <tr>
                                <th>No Employee</th>
                              <th>Tanggal Lahir</th>
                              <th>Firstname</th>
                              <th>Lastname</th>
                              <th>Gender</th>
                              <th>Hiredate</th>
                          </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tfoot>
                          <tr>
                            <th>No Employee</th>
                          <th>Tanggal Lahir</th>
                          <th>Firstname</th>
                          <th>Lastname</th>
                          <th>Gender</th>
                          <th>Hiredate</th>
                          </tr>
                      </tfoot>
                  </table>
```

any idea why the export button missing in adminlte? Already Include the bootstrap button `buttons.bootstrap.min.js`

Comment: did you check console? Maybe you'll get a hint from there.

Comment: And one more thing where have you defined `newExportAction` function?

Comment: already defined newExportAction and theres' no error on console developer, i'll try to redeploy adminlte, maybe its conflicted with datatable from admin lte :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -  add your external js files in this tag to work with adminLTE:

```
@section('js') 
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
@stop
```

Answer (score 1):

I added the following and It works like charm for me.

[At the header]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
```

[At the bottom of the footer]

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
```

These script are the latest as of 18-04-2020